# ASP NET MVC 5 - No return view do post não esta atualizando campos

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Quando faço o post do formulário este chama uma API que retorna os campos "Valor do Cambio" e "Valor Calculado", os valores são carregados no objeto model, porém o campo na tela não esta sendo atualizado.

[image: Objeto]

[image: Tela]
[image: Razor]

Comment: Olá @paula bem vinda ao StackOverflow, sugiro que você edite sua pergunta e coloque o código como código formatado ao invés de uma imagem pois isto facilida que os usuário copiem e testem seu código.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar uma solução. [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471310/textboxfor-value-not-updating-after-post)